# google compute engine instance unable to connect between nodes using internal ip

Tags: google-compute-engine

it was working fine before i created a new instance of my existing instance.
when i redeployed the snapshot of both instance onto a another zone,
i wasn't able to ping or connect to both instances via lan ip.

one instance is on
10.240.0.5 and another on 10.240.0.6
with 10.240.0.0/16

its on the same network,
and i have an existing firewall rules that allow all connection ports between nodes, but for some reason it's not working. 
so i deleted the existing setting and reenter a new firewall rule
default-all-lan

```
Network

default
Source IP ranges

10.240.0.0/16
Allowed protocols and ports

tcp:1-65535
udp:1-65535
icmp
```

i still can't ping or connect to any tcp port including web port 80.
but when i tried to wget http://node2_externalip from node1, it works!
what could be the issue?

Comment: is the default route for internal communication still available on the network? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#network_routes

Answer (score 1):

That is a strange behavior. If a VM is recreated in the same network, Google Firewall rules will still apply.  In general there are a couple of things you might want to look at:

1) Check that the Google Firewall rule is still valid. For example if you recreate the VMs without metadata tags and the [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create) was using them, traffic will get blocked.

2) Confirm that the VM itself is not running a firewall that is dropping the packets.

3) Check that the VM has a service listening on the appropriate port [netstat --listen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538208/how-to-check-opened-closed-port-on-my-computer)

4) As already mentioned, check the [routes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/routes) on Google project.

The use of tools like [nmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap) or [telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) can also help to troubleshoot.